# Using links to point ~ipad resources to @2x resources

Tags: iphone, ios

I've been looking for a solution to the issue of duplicating hundreds of `@2x` files only to rename them `~ipad`.  I tried a number of ideas which mostly involved doing it in code.  I'll post as the answer to my own question what I found works well:  Use symlinks to point `~ipad` to `@2x` files.

I just wanted to document it here as I have not seen this solution in my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to create a link to the `@2x` file and name that link `~ipad`.

This is NOT the "Alias" command found in Finder.

Manually you'd use the Terminal and enter something like this:

```
ln -s image@2x.png image~ipad.png
```

Now when you run your code any of the UIImage methods that intelligently grab a device appropriate file will use the `@2x` files when running on an iPad.  Links are about 16 bytes on disk, so this saves a ton of storage.

I also wrote a little bash script to automagically go through a directory and create `~ipad` links for every `@2x` file it finds:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Script to batch create symlinks that point ~ipad files to @2X files

# To run:
# Copy to the directory where the files are located
# Enter the following at the terminal prompt:
# bash create_ipad_image_links.txt

# For every @2x file we find in this directory we create a symlink

for file in *@2x.png
do
  echo "link: ${file//@2x/~ipad} to: $file" 
  ln -s $file ${file//@2x/~ipad}
done
```

Usage instructions in the code above. Please comment if this can be improved in any way.  I'm sure there are better (slicker?) ways to approach this.