# Using @2x files for a NonRetina iPad when @2x~ipad images exist

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have 3 images, file.png, file@2x.png and file@2x~ipad.png. I want to use file@2x.png on Retina iPhone and nonRetina iPad.

I want to **set the images in interface builder**. The iPhone works fine, where I set file.png in the xib and it loads file@2x.png on Retina iPhone. But on nonRetina iPad, file@2x~ipad.png is loaded even though I specified file@2x.png.

Is there a way to set nonRetina iPad to default to the @2x version when a ~ipad version doesn't exist through interface builder/xibs? (*I'm well aware of loading images with different extensions through code by writing custom loading code*) Are there any settings or plists I can change?

**I don't want to make duplicates** of the same image just to be able to name them differently.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea if this would work, but you could try symbolic links from the standard filename to the file you really want to load.

Comment: @EricS I read about that too and I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use symbolic links to point `myImage~iPad.png` to `myImage@2x.png`. Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223119/313875

Summary of this answer (read - someone else's answer to another question, so please go up-vote them!):

Use `ln -s myImage@2x.png myImage~ipad.png` for each image. Or use a script:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Script to batch create symlinks that point ~ipad files to @2X files

# To run:
# Copy to the directory where the files are located
# Enter the following at the terminal prompt:
# bash create_ipad_image_links.txt

# For every @2x file we find in this directory we create a symlink

for file in *@2x.png
do
  echo "link: ${file//@2x/~ipad} to: $file" 
  ln -s $file ${file//@2x/~ipad}
done
```

Comment: I do not know if compiling with links will create two separate copies of the image on device (I have not tried though). I did try using NSFileManager to create hardlinks on the device, but it seems that you can't create links (not even symlinks) with bundle items because of "write permissions"...even though I'm not even writing anything. I am not saying your answer will not work, just that I wish for a solution through my app's code and not during development; however this solution has helped me a lot so I will mark it correct

Comment: Yeah, you can't create any form of link inside the bundle. Glad my answer helped, even if it's not what you hoped for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I ended up doing this but I put it in a Run Script for the project so it gets run when the project compiles. Also, I had to change all my references to 2x in ipad xibs to ~ipad, rename all my 2x files to ~ipad, then create symlinks from ~ipad to 2x in the run script. It works! If I didn't rename from 2x to ~ipad, the ipad xibs would still be trying to get retina versions since the file specified in the xib was 2x.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this without adding duplicate files is by naming the iPad version `file@2x@2x.png`. You can then set the iPad version using either `[UIImage imageNamed:@"file@2x"];` or set the image to `file@2x.png` to have `file@2x@2x.png` used on retina iPad and `file@2x.png` on normal iPad. That way there is no duplication.

Comment: The problem is that I need this through interface builder/xibs, so I can't use imageNamed, nor do I have any control over which version is loaded. I am asking the question to see if there's any settings or plists I can tweak. I have already programmed code to handle files loaded through imageNamed, so that @2x is loaded if ~ipad doesn't exist, but my code can't be used for loading xibs.

Comment: That's why I said that it isn't exactly what you want. Actually, are you creating two nibs (one for iPhone and one for iPad)? In that case just use the `file@2x.png` rather than `file.png` as the image and `file@2x@2x.png` will be used on retina iPad as it should.

Comment: Yes I have two nibs. I will try that!

Answer (score -1):

Try creating `file~ipad.png`. Non-retina iPads should look for that file first.

Comment: I don't want to make duplicate images, and I need it to be @2x so Retina iPhone will use it.

Comment: You don't understand the search order of images. Using the image~<device> name convention forces the device in question to use that image. E.g., you can also use image~iphone.png AND image~iphone@2x.png. jrtc27's answer is roughly equivalent to mine, with the added convenience of symlinks instead of image copies.

Comment: First, I think it's @2x~iphone for the retina iphone modifier. Second, I know about the order of images. I know why what I want to do doesn't work (I'm using @2x on a nonretina ipad, so it assumes I want to use retina on the ipad and tries to find the most specific file, which is @2x~ipad). I can't create a copy because that is a waste of room. Nor can I rename the file because the retina iphone needs it.